# What's the symbol that makes one action unique?

Tags: action

When I use the command `cleos get actions <account_name> -j`,I got three actions which have different receivers, but belong to the same transfer.
I know that the three actions are for accounts who has contract、who is the from account and who is the to account.
Could I use the field `act_digest` to mark one transfer action, because I don't want to write down three repeated actions?

```
{
    "actions": [{
        "global_action_seq": 6516,
        "account_action_seq": 1,
        "block_num": 6506,
        "block_time": "2018-05-15T03:43:15.000",
        "action_trace": {
            "receipt": {
                "receiver": "eosio.token",
                "act_digest": "cc3d56ed6ebe9f34a39a5e042c5d6c3a28131c5f60a708b8eaa6518b1a391540",
                "global_sequence": 6516,
                "recv_sequence": 4,
                "auth_sequence": [
                    ["user",
                        1
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "act": {
                "account": "eosio.token",
                "name": "transfer",
                "authorization": [{
                    "actor": "user",
                    "permission": "active"
                }],
                "data": {
                    "from": "user",
                    "to": "tester",
                    "quantity": "2500.0000 EOS",
                    "memo": "m"
                },
                "hex_data": "00000000007015d6000000005c95b1ca40787d010000000004454f5300000000016d"
            },
            "elapsed": 620,
            "cpu_usage": 0,
            "console": "transfer from user to tester 2500.0000 EOS\nuser balance: 17500.0000 EOS\ntester balance: 2500.0000 EOS\n",
            "total_cpu_usage": 0,
            "trx_id": "a4b4d3303c8034dd2298f87c8481a001e009871a16e3365a74703bf138dfdf47",
            "inline_traces": [{
                "receipt": {
                    "receiver": "user",
                    "act_digest": "cc3d56ed6ebe9f34a39a5e042c5d6c3a28131c5f60a708b8eaa6518b1a391540",
                    "global_sequence": 6517,
                    "recv_sequence": 2,
                    "auth_sequence": [
                        ["user",
                            2
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "act": {
                    "account": "eosio.token",
                    "name": "transfer",
                    "authorization": [{
                        "actor": "user",
                        "permission": "active"
                    }],
                    "data": {
                        "from": "user",
                        "to": "tester",
                        "quantity": "2500.0000 EOS",
                        "memo": "m"
                    },
                    "hex_data": "00000000007015d6000000005c95b1ca40787d010000000004454f5300000000016d"
                },
                "elapsed": 4,
                "cpu_usage": 0,
                "console": "",
                "total_cpu_usage": 0,
                "trx_id": "a4b4d3303c8034dd2298f87c8481a001e009871a16e3365a74703bf138dfdf47",
                "inline_traces": []
            }, {
                "receipt": {
                    "receiver": "tester",
                    "act_digest": "cc3d56ed6ebe9f34a39a5e042c5d6c3a28131c5f60a708b8eaa6518b1a391540",
                    "global_sequence": 6518,
                    "recv_sequence": 1,
                    "auth_sequence": [
                        ["user",
                            3
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "act": {
                    "account": "eosio.token",
                    "name": "transfer",
                    "authorization": [{
                        "actor": "user",
                        "permission": "active"
                    }],
                    "data": {
                        "from": "user",
                        "to": "tester",
                        "quantity": "2500.0000 EOS",
                        "memo": "m"
                    },
                    "hex_data": "00000000007015d6000000005c95b1ca40787d010000000004454f5300000000016d"
                },
                "elapsed": 4,
                "cpu_usage": 0,
                "console": "",
                "total_cpu_usage": 0,
                "trx_id": "a4b4d3303c8034dd2298f87c8481a001e009871a16e3365a74703bf138dfdf47",
                "inline_traces": []
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "global_action_seq": 6517,
        "account_action_seq": 2,
        "block_num": 6506,
        "block_time": "2018-05-15T03:43:15.000",
        "action_trace": {
            "receipt": {
                "receiver": "user",
                "act_digest": "cc3d56ed6ebe9f34a39a5e042c5d6c3a28131c5f60a708b8eaa6518b1a391540",
                "global_sequence": 6517,
                "recv_sequence": 2,
                "auth_sequence": [
                    ["user",
                        2
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "act": {
                "account": "eosio.token",
                "name": "transfer",
                "authorization": [{
                    "actor": "user",
                    "permission": "active"
                }],
                "data": {
                    "from": "user",
                    "to": "tester",
                    "quantity": "2500.0000 EOS",
                    "memo": "m"
                },
                "hex_data": "00000000007015d6000000005c95b1ca40787d010000000004454f5300000000016d"
            },
            "elapsed": 4,
            "cpu_usage": 0,
            "console": "",
            "total_cpu_usage": 0,
            "trx_id": "a4b4d3303c8034dd2298f87c8481a001e009871a16e3365a74703bf138dfdf47",
            "inline_traces": []
        }
    }, {
        "global_action_seq": 6518,
        "account_action_seq": 3,
        "block_num": 6506,
        "block_time": "2018-05-15T03:43:15.000",
        "action_trace": {
            "receipt": {
                "receiver": "tester",
                "act_digest": "cc3d56ed6ebe9f34a39a5e042c5d6c3a28131c5f60a708b8eaa6518b1a391540",
                "global_sequence": 6518,
                "recv_sequence": 1,
                "auth_sequence": [
                    ["user",
                        3
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "act": {
                "account": "eosio.token",
                "name": "transfer",
                "authorization": [{
                    "actor": "user",
                    "permission": "active"
                }],
                "data": {
                    "from": "user",
                    "to": "tester",
                    "quantity": "2500.0000 EOS",
                    "memo": "m"
                },
                "hex_data": "00000000007015d6000000005c95b1ca40787d010000000004454f5300000000016d"
            },
            "elapsed": 4,
            "cpu_usage": 0,
            "console": "",
            "total_cpu_usage": 0,
            "trx_id": "a4b4d3303c8034dd2298f87c8481a001e009871a16e3365a74703bf138dfdf47",
            "inline_traces": []
        }
    }],
    "last_irreversible_block": 112987
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `act_digest` to group them because analyzing the code here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/3016381ec3a899e19623377d92bd63af534cacfe/libraries/chain/apply_context.cpp#L59 -- it looks like it uses the same `act_digest` while it increment the others fields sequences.

But I would consider to filter by receiver because I'm pretty sure that you can always be specific on your application wants to trace: the contract (`eosio.token`), the transfer sender `tester` or the transfer receiver `user`?

Comment: Yes, we can filter it by receiver. But in my circumstances, I should monitor not only `sender account`, but also `receiver account`. If I can't make sure one unique action, there would be many repeated actions in my db.It seems that `act_digest` is the value of action hash. Thank you very much.