# Multiple action_traces, which one is the "good" one?

Tags: nodeos, transactions, block-producer

Sorry if I'm asking a lot of questions but you're really helpful and I'm getting a better understanding of the platform every day thanks to you ;)

I'm having a hard time figuring out why some transactions are "duplicated" whereas some are not. I found on this forum people referring to `act_digest` as being a potential unique identifier (same `act_digest` = same transaction) but amongst there various transactions, which one is to be considered the "valid" one? How can I double check that?

They have much in common but for example, the following information aren't identical from one to another "transaction":

- global_sequence
- recv_sequence
- block_num (this one is interesting as the block_num is different but the block_time is identical)
- producer_block_id
- createdAt

Is it possible that the same transaction was processed by different BP but only 1 is to be considered as valid but it doesn't matter which one?

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Comment: A little up comment as I found [this topic here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/332/whats-the-symbol-that-makes-one-action-unique) but it's just a guess, anyone as a more definitive answer? Document is non existent on that "issue" and I really don't understand why some transactions have dozen of identical `act_digest` whereas others has merely one?